# How to make QML WebView Element use Qt::openUrlExternally for all 'new windows'?

Tags: qt, qml

How to make [QML WebView Element](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qml-webview.html) use [Qt::openUrlExternally](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qml-qt.html#openUrlExternally-method) instead of some visual [newWindowComponent](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qml-webview.html#newWindowComponent-prop)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this using QML. You can do this with the standard `QWebView`, but there isn't a way to access this functionality from within QML. You would need to re-wrap `QWebView` and expose more functions.

An example using the standard C++ interfaces:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWebKit>
#include "handler.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWebView view;
    view.load(QUrl::fromUserInput("http://qt-project.org/"));

    view.page()->setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage::DelegateAllLinks);

    LinkHandler handler;

    QObject::connect(
        &view, SIGNAL(linkClicked(const QUrl&)),
        &handler, SLOT(open(const QUrl&)));

    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**handler.hpp**

```
#ifndef _HANDLER_HPP_
#define _HANDLER_HPP_

#include <QtGui>

class LinkHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        LinkHandler();

    public slots:
        void open(const QUrl& url);
};

#endif
```

**handler.cpp**

```
#include "handler.hpp"

LinkHandler::LinkHandler() : QObject() {}

void LinkHandler::open(const QUrl& url)
{
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(Qt4 4.8 REQUIRED QtCore QtGui QtWebkit)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})

qt4_wrap_cpp(MOC_FILES handler.hpp)
add_executable(test
    test.cpp
    handler.hpp
    handler.cpp
    ${MOC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(test ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: As I explained in my answer the QML WebView Element doesn't provide the full interface of QWebView, so you can't use the standard QML WebView to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will open *all* links in new windows, but it is trivial to add detection for `target=_blank`

```
WebView{
    id: webView
    url: "samples/sample.html"
    preferredWidth: parent.width
    enabled: false
    onLoadFinished: {
        evaluateJavaScript(' \
            var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); \
            for (var i in els){ \
                els[i].onclick = function(e){e.preventDefault(); qml.qmlCall(this.getAttribute("href")); return false;} \
            } \
        ')
        enabled = true;
        }
    javaScriptWindowObjects: QtObject {
        WebView.windowObjectName: "qml"

        function qmlCall(url) {
            console.log(url);
            Qt.openUrlExternally(url)
        }
    }
}
```

It boils down to adding some javascript in the webview after it has loaded to override the default action of links and pass the value of the `href` attribute to qml, and open externally from there.